# In python How can I parse a JSON string, which has value regex, with slashes(\) without breaking JSON structure?

Tags: python, json

My application gets a request with regex in its JSON value.

```
{ "regex" : "^1\.0(\.\\d+)?$" }
```

I use below code to parse it:

```
parsedData = json.loads(requestData)
```

But it fails because of non-JSON characters.

I tried many ways, One of them is this

Bease64 encoding and decoding :

```
>>> s = '^1\.0(\.\\d+)?$'
>>> e = base64.b64encode('^1\.0(\.\d+)?$')
>>> e
'XjFcLjAoXC5cZCspPyQ='
>>> d = base64.b64decode(e)
>>> d
'^1\\.0(\\.\\d+)?$'
```

Observe the output - `'^1\\.0(\\.\\d+)?$'`  : 1 extra slash added.

Clearly now not able to distinguish between the one with 2 slashes and one slashes.

Since the data is regex, I want it in the original format in a variable.

How can I get that?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the incoming json before it reaches you? Can you modify the client sending the json. Basically you'll need to replace each slash with a double slash. So you'll have '\\\\' and '\\' for double and single slashes respectively. (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that your json isn't properly encoded, so you're having trouble decoding it.  This is a chicken & egg problem.

```
>>> import json
>>> r = r'^1\.0(\.\d+)?$'
>>> print r
^1\.0(\.\d+)?$
>>> print json.dumps(r)
"^1\\.0(\\.\\d+)?$"
```

You need to investigate how the json is being created before it's passed to you (if you're in control there) or reach out to the person generating it.

Comment: In output I want : '^1\.0(\.\\d+)?$' . I tried with - str.replace('\\\\','\\')   . Not working

Comment: But this worked:  print str.replace("\\\\", "\\")  .  I dint get why? WHich should I consider as right answer?

Comment: I actually don't believe you want `'^1\.0(\.\\d+)?$'` in the output.  That's what I'm trying to express.  That string isn't valid JSON encoded representation of a regular expression from another language.  If you were to use that as a regex in that form, you'd match `1.0.\d`, not `1.0.3`.  I believe you want to match the latter, in which case, the JSON you receive wasn't properly encoded, hence your trouble decoding it.